# See what wildcard what used in SQL Query

Tags: sql

Is there a way to see what character(s) replace the %/wildcard in an SQL Query?

Say

```
        $exhibitions = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
            WHERE meta_key LIKE  'dates_%_startdate'
            ORDER BY meta_value
            LIMIT 0 , 30" );
```

If the meta_key-column in a result was 'dates_0_startdate' I'd like to get just the zero somehow.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? Should be quite easy using a regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, replace(replace(meta_key, 'dates_', ''), '_startdate', '')
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key LIKE  'dates_%_startdate'
ORDER BY meta_value
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24457)

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning, in MSSQL an underscore is a Single Character wildcard.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Also in MySQL appearently: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Why should that be a "warning"? This is how wildcards are defined in (standard) SQL.

Comment: Actually the table is created by wordpress, tons of columns are named using underscores.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_key,'dates_',''),'_startdate','') 
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key LIKE  'dates_%_startdate'
ORDER BY meta_value
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what form of SQL you are using.  If you're using MSSQL (which you aren't by the looks of things from your get_results) you can use SUBSTRING to return the info which works like SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )

```
get_results( "SELECT SUBSTRING(meta_key, 7, 1) FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE meta_key LIKE  'dates_%_startdate'
        ORDER BY meta_value
        LIMIT 0 , 30" );
```